Is it possible to allow URL parameters to be passed in like switches?
I'm wondering if it's possible to implement a REST API endpoint in ASP.NET where a URL parameter can be passed in like a switch (as opposed to having to pass in a boolean parameter that has to be explicitly set in the URL to true or false).
I have this controller:
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TestController : Controller {

    [HttpGet("example")]
    public IActionResult Example([FromQuery] bool? myswitch) {
        return Ok(new {
            ParameterValue = myswitch ?? false,
            Message = myswitch.HasValue && myswitch.Value 
                ? "Parameter is present" 
                : "Parameter is absent/false"
        });
    }
}

If I pass in http://localhost:5005/test/example?myswitch I want to receive:
{
    "parameterValue": true,
    "message": "Parameter is present"
}

But instead, I'm receiving:
{
    "parameterValue": false,
    "message": "Parameter is absent/false"
}

Is there a different data type than boolean I could use for this purpose?

This can be accomplished by checking to see if the parameter name is found in the request query dictionary:
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TestController : Controller {

    [HttpGet("example")]
    public IActionResult Example() {
        bool myswitch = Request.Query.ContainsKey("myswitch");
        return Ok(new {
            ParameterValue = myswitch ?? false,
            Message = myswitch.HasValue && myswitch.Value 
                ? "Parameter is present" 
                : "Parameter is absent"
        });
    }
}

